# Incremental concatenation of columns per row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, select, concatenation

I am trying to write an Oracle or MS SQL script which outputs the first row containing the cell value in column A, second row contains the cell value of column A concatenated with column B and separated by a comma,
third row contains the cell values of column A, B and C concatenated and separated by a comma.

Suppose the following SQL Table:

```
|columnA |columnB|columnC |columnD |columnF |columnG |  
|--------|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  matty | lucy  |  james | mike   | tala   | mark   | 
|  jana  | steph |  alex  | mohd   | hani   | elie   |
```

The output would be:

```
matty 
matty,lucy
matty,lucy,james
matty,lucy,james,mike 
matty,lucy,james,mike,tala
matty,lucy,james,mike,tala,mark
jana
jana,steph
jana,steph,alex
jana,steph,alex,mohd
jana,steph,alex,mohd,hani
jana,steph,alex,mohd,hani,elie
```

How should I write the SQL select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to unpivot data and make recursive concatenation (Oracle solution):

```
--data 
with t(a, b, c, d, e, f) as (
    select 'matty', 'lucy',  'james', 'mike', 'tala', 'mark' from dual union all 
    select 'jana ', 'steph', 'alex',  'mohd', 'hani', 'elie' from dual )
-- end of data
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(name, ','), ',') path
  from (select rownum r1, a, b, c, d, e, f from t) 
        unpivot (name for r2 in (a as 1, b as 2, c as 3, d as 4, e as 5, f as 6))
  connect by prior r1 = r1 and r2 = prior r2 + 1
  start with r2 = 1
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c9d7ee6a492012b59e10369a2e35323)</sup>**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`:

```
select tt.*
from table t cross apply
     ( values (columnA, null, null, null, null, null),
              (columnA, columnB, null, null, null, null),
               . . . 
              (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnF, columnG)    
     ) tt(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6);
```

If you want to combine all the data into single column then use `concat()`  :

```
select tt.*
from table t cross apply
     ( values (columnA),
              (concat(columnA, ',', columnB)),
              (concat(columnA, ',', columnB, ',', columnC)),
              (concat(columnA, ',', columnB, ',', columnC, ',', columnD)),
              (concat(columnA, ',', columnB, ',', columnC, ',', columnD, ',', columnF)),
              (concat(columnA, ',', columnB, ',', columnC, ',', columnD, ',', columnF, ',', columnG))
     ) tt(cols);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a version that works in both databases:

```
select colA
from t
union all
select concat(Col1, concat(',', colB))
from t
union all
select concat(concat(Col1, concat(',', colB)), concat(',', colC))
from t
union all
. . .
```